# Analyzing branded vs non-branded SEO transactions using Google Analytics and Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, keywords

I have a well indexed site say: `example.com`. I use webmaster for keyword/traffic analysis, Google Analytics for many other things like performance, transactions calculations(using sale performance, e-commerce(), etc.

Now through Google Search Console, I know the SEO traffic of my site eparated by branded vs non branded search terms.  For Example: 1000 users on site through SEO, out of which 800 come through non branded search terms like `best time to play cricket`
and branded like `best time to play cricket example.com`.

Google Analytics gives me total e-commerce report transactions: Say these transactions are 100 /day with SEO attributing to 25 transactions. I want to get how many out of these 25 SEO transactions were done by branded and how much by non-branded.

There is an option to link Google Analytics with Google Search Console which I have done, but its not helping in getting query on search engine vs transaction ratio. Can we get this done through these tools?

Answer (score 2):

Analytics allows you to customise channel groupings:
[image: Custom Channel Groupings]

You can define brand terms and use these to set up a customised grouping. Then use it to filter your conversions in Analytics. I would suggest doing it on an alternative view to the default - that way you can switch back and forth depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks Liam, we are looking on this solution to find if this works for us.